# How to create algolia autocomplete custom renderer using react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia

I am tickling with Algolia autocomplete, and I am trying to replicate their custom renderer in react using the class component. This is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-http-sr5n8?file=/src/App.js) of the minimal demo of custom renderer using functional component,

and here is my attempt to convert it into a class component.

```
import { createAutocomplete } from "@algolia/autocomplete-core";
import { getAlgoliaResults } from "@algolia/autocomplete-preset-algolia";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import React from "react";

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  "latency",
  "6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76"
);
// let autocomplete;
class AutocompleteClass extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.autocomplete = null;
    this.state = {
      autocompleteState: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.inputRef.current) {
      return undefined;
    }

    this.autocomplete = createAutocomplete({
      onStateChange({ state }) {
        // (2) Synchronize the Autocomplete state with the React state.
        this.setState({ autocompleteState: state });
      },
      getSources() {
        return [
          {
            sourceId: "products",
            getItems({ query }) {
              return getAlgoliaResults({
                searchClient,
                queries: [
                  {
                    indexName: "instant_search",
                    query,
                    params: {
                      hitsPerPage: 5,
                      highlightPreTag: "<mark>",
                      highlightPostTag: "</mark>",
                    },
                  },
                ],
              });
            },
            getItemUrl({ item }) {
              return item.url;
            },
          },
        ];
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { autocompleteState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="aa-Autocomplete" {...this.autocomplete?.getRootProps({})}>
        <form
          className="aa-Form"
          {...this.autocomplete?.getFormProps({
            inputElement: this.inputRef.current,
          })}
        >
          <div className="aa-InputWrapperPrefix">
            <label
              className="aa-Label"
              {...this.autocomplete?.getLabelProps({})}
            >
              Search
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="aa-InputWrapper">
            <input
              className="aa-Input"
              ref={this.inputRef}
              {...this.autocomplete?.getInputProps({})}
            />componentDidUpdate()
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="aa-Panel" {...this.autocomplete?.getPanelProps({})}>
          {autocompleteState.isOpen &&
            autocompleteState.collections.map((collection, index) => {
              const { source, items } = collection;

              return (
                <div key={`source-${index}`} className="aa-Source">
                  {items.length > 0 && (
                    <ul
                      className="aa-List"
                      {...this.autocomplete?.getListProps()}
                    >
                      {items.map((item) => (
                        <li
                          key={item.objectID}
                          className="aa-Item"
                          {...this.autocomplete?.getItemProps({
                            item,
                            source,
                          })}
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AutocompleteClass;
```

and the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bohr-1rykm?file=/src/App.js) of the same version, I also tried using `componentDidUpdate()` but no luck, any lead where I did wrong would be much appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, dont know why you need it made into class component but here you go:

```js
import { createAutocomplete } from "@algolia/autocomplete-core";
import { getAlgoliaResults } from "@algolia/autocomplete-preset-algolia";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import React from "react";

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  "latency",
  "6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76"
);
// let autocomplete;
class AutocompleteClass extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      autocompleteState: {},
      query: '',
    };
    this.autocomplete = createAutocomplete({
      onStateChange: this.onChange,
      getSources() {
        return [
          {
            sourceId: "products",
            getItems({ query }) {
              console.log('getting query', query)
              return getAlgoliaResults({
                searchClient,
                queries: [
                  {
                    indexName: "instant_search",
                    query,
                    params: {
                      hitsPerPage: 5,
                      highlightPreTag: "<mark>",
                      highlightPostTag: "</mark>"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              });
            },
            getItemUrl({ item }) {
              return item.url;
            }
          }
        ];
      }
    });
  }

  onChange = ({ state }) => {
    console.log(state)
    this.setState({ autocompleteState: state, query: state.query });
  }

  render() {
    const { autocompleteState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="aa-Autocomplete" {...this.autocomplete?.getRootProps({})}>
        <form
          className="aa-Form"
          {...this.autocomplete?.getFormProps({
            inputElement: this.state.query
          })}
        >
          <div className="aa-InputWrapperPrefix">
            <label
              className="aa-Label"
              {...this.autocomplete?.getLabelProps({})}
            >
              Search
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="aa-InputWrapper">
            <input
              className="aa-Input"
              value={this.state.query}
              {...this.autocomplete?.getInputProps({})}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="aa-Panel" {...this.autocomplete?.getPanelProps({})}>
          {autocompleteState.isOpen &&
            autocompleteState.collections.map((collection, index) => {
              const { source, items } = collection;

              return (
                <div key={`source-${index}`} className="aa-Source">
                  {items.length > 0 && (
                    <ul
                      className="aa-List"
                      {...this.autocomplete?.getListProps()}
                    >
                      {items.map((item) => (
                        <li
                          key={item.objectID}
                          className="aa-Item"
                          {...this.autocomplete?.getItemProps({
                            item,
                            source
                          })}
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AutocompleteClass;
```

Anyway the componentDidMount is called only once, and because of ref object is undefined it just returned from it.
Also messing with `this` in class components is quite a bad idea (that is why func components are recommended)

Comment: it works like a charm Thank you I was banging my head to the wall for this.